# Edit text file using sed or awk

Tags: sed, awk

I have a sample text file as shown below:

```
>chr1 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr10 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr11 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr12 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>AAEX03020170.1 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
>AAEX03022270.1 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
>JH373398.1dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
>JH373568.1dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
```

The first four starts with `chr1`, `chr10`,`chr11` and `chr12` and the rest starts with a common prefix `AAEX` and `JH`.

I would like to delete all the data from lines starting with `AAEX` and `JH` i.e. the output should be like:

```
>chr1 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr10 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr11 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr12 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
```

The original file has many such lines starting with 'AAEX' and 'JH' and would like to convert as shown above. Any help?

Comment: Formatting of questions like this is very important please try to format your questions in future so no information gets hidden by mistake http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$ awk '/>[AJ]/{if(!f++)print ">chrX";next}NF' file
>chr1 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr10 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr11 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chr12 dna:chromosome chromosome:CanFam3.1:1:1:122678785:1 REF
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
>chrX
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNTATGTGAGAAGATAGCTGAA
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. And, could it be done in such a way that, all the data below the lines starting with 'AAE' and 'J' are written under the existing chr*. i.e. in this case we have written under a new ">chrX", can we write it under >chr12 or >chr11 or >chr10 or >chr1?

Comment: Under `char12` simple just don't `print >chrX`. To print under any of the others you would have to buffer the file. Either way both are simple modifications. Please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Comment: I am a newbie with awk, could you kindly add the modification to the above command?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^>(AAEX|JH)/{x;/./{x;d};x;s/.*/>chrX/p;h;d};/^>/{x;s/.*//;x}' file
```